# Using THIS inside a click event managed by addEventListener

Tags: javascript, this

I am trying this very simple code to realize a TicTacToe in plain Javascript:

```
function inizializza()
  {
  var x = document.querySelectorAll(".riga div");
  var i;
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    document.querySelectorAll(".riga div")[i].addEventListener("click",
    cambia);
     }

  }

var segno = "X";

function cambia()
 {
 if (this.innerHTML != "")
   {
   alert("ERRORE!")
   }
 else
  {
  this.innerHTML = segno;
  if (segno == "X")
     segno = "O";
  else
    segno = "X";
  }
 }
```

Function inizializza() is called on body load.

When you click on a .riga div (a cell in my game table), the event click should change the text displayed in the cell: X or O. But this is not working, because I can't use "this" kewyword to retrieve clicked object properties.

How can I do it?

Thanks a lot!
Giancarlo

Comment: what about `e.target`?

Answer (score 1):

you can use closures here

check the following snippet

```js
window.onload = function() {
  inizializza();
}

function inizializza() {
  var x = document.querySelectorAll(".riga div");
  var i;
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    document.querySelectorAll(".riga div")[i].addEventListener("click",function(event){
      cambia(this);
    });
  }

}

var segno = "X";

function cambia(obj) {
  if (obj.innerHTML == "") {
    alert("ERRORE!")
  } else {
    obj.innerHTML = segno;
    if (segno == "X")
      segno = "O";
    else
      segno = "X";
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="riga">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>X</div>

</div>
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

You can use the event object passed as the first argument of the click event.

event.target will work for most of the browser and event.srcElement works with few old microsoft browsers.

```
function inizializza()
{
  var x = document.querySelectorAll(".riga div");
  console.log(x);
  var i;
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    document.querySelectorAll(".riga div")[i].addEventListener("click",
    cambia);
     }
 }

 var segno = "X";

 function cambia(event)
 {

  var element = event.target || event.srcElement;

  if (target.innerHTML !== "")
  {
   alert("ERRORE!")
  }
  else
  {
  this.innerHTML = segno;
  if (segno == "X")
     segno = "O";
  else
    segno = "X";
  }
 }
```

Working example : https://plnkr.co/edit/NaTwU7XmmU9sLgNiFrjO?p=preview